# Rails 5 Unpermitted parameter: organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error `Unpermitted parameter: organization` when I submit a sign up form for my user. I am using an 'auth from scratch' variant, not devise. Here is my code:

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization
    has_secure_password
end
```

## organization.rb

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

## users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @user = User.new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.build_organization(user_params[:organization_attributes])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin,
        organization_attributes: :name)
    end
end
```

## new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :organization do |org| %>
    <%= 'Organization or Company Name' %><br />
    <%= org.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :admin %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :admin %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is a peek at the console upon submission...

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lhzxsTF43PiGKwMXly/fufGoVNEMUgqymwtMkhCkNtmolArIqbUjuo/qxYUVpFxIfaB4qVV2sumDqa5O2ggLbA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"myuser@user.com", "organization"=>{"name"=>"myOrg"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
Unpermitted parameter: organization
Unpermitted parameter: organization
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "organizations" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2016-07-25 15:39:56 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-25 15:39:56 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "organization_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "myuser@user.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$MEEXO6bU9FGwMv3WOvdYheL.1iGhx4eeDVo67qp.OPmh1BJHs0z0G"], ["organization_id", 10], ["created_at", 2016-07-25 15:39:56 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-25 15:39:56 UTC]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 64ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Me thinks the root of the issue is the `organization"=>{"name"=>"myOrg"}` when the parameters are submitted, it should be organization_attributes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct, but there are a couple other issues.

1. Change the strong_params option to `organization_attributes` as you mentioned.
2. You have the `accepts_nested_attributes` backwards. Because you are creating a user with `user_params`, then your User model needs `accepts_nested_attributes :organization`, while organization does not need it (unless you use it elsewhere).
3. After tweaking your models, you won't need to explicitly build the organization anymore via `@user.build_organization(user_params[:organization_attributes])`. That line can just be removed.

Lastly, I just want to point out that you may not want to allow the `admin` flag to be passed through, as that could be a security risk. Obviously don't know your app, but just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Thanks phoffer, that was 'mostly' it. I switched the accepts_nested_attributes in the models, and also changed f.fields_for :organization to f.fields_for :organization_attributes in the form/view and that worked.